# disable explain in Rails 3.2

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-execution-plan

Is it possible to disable the new the explain functionality in Rails 3.2 globally via configuration?  I'm using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 3.2.1 and there appear to be some bugs with the explain (show plan) portion of the gem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To cite from http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-explain/

> New applications get
>
> ```
> config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
> ```
>
> in `config/environments/development.rb`. Active Record monitors queries and if they take more than that threshold their query plan will be logged using warn.
>
> [...]
>
> By default the threshold is `nil` in the test and production environments, which means the feature is disabled.

so just set

```
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = nil
```

Answer (score 10):

You can disable auto-explain by setting `config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = nil` in your **config/environments/development.rb**

Comment: When I answered the question, there were no other answers. We must have been answering/typing at the same time.

Comment: A glance at the answers's timestamps is verification of this.

Answer (score 1):

You should note that `config.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds` has been completely removed in Rails 4.0 & 4.1. In 4.1 it will throw a full error.

See https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9400/files

If you upgrade, comment that line out.