# How to disable running explain command in dev mode in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to disable running explain command in dev mode in Rails3

```
   User Load (615.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 12 LIMIT 1

      EXPLAIN (604.5ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 12 LIMIT 1

    EXPLAIN for: SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 12 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777203/disable-explain-in-rails-3-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#automatic-explain), setting the `config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds` to `nil` will disable it.